# Error while trying to import a project into eclipse workspace by means of command line using jenkins Job

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, jenkins, project

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-02-03 13:23:15.443
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.updateTable(StorageManager.java:512)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:709)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initFileManager(BaseStorage.java:220)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(BaseStorage.java:154)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:192)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:262)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

This is the error that I get when I try to import project into workspace using the below mentioned eclipse command

```
   tresos_cmd.bat [<system_property>...] [-data <workspace>] 
                   importProject [-c] <project path>...
```

I am trying to execute this command in jenkins execute windows batch command section. Can anyone please explain to me how can I get rid of this error.

Comment: Were you able to fix your issue?